# Python or Perl for creating an Excel spreadsheet on Linux

Tags: python, perl, excel

I have a Python program running on a Linux machine that writes out data to a CSV file. The client now wants the CSV data written to an Excel file. The Excel file needs to be based on a template - company Logo etc. It also needs to highlight certain rows if a date field is in a certain range.

The program is proprietary so I don't want to use anything that will make it come under the GPL.

Is there a Python solution that meets these requirements? Would it be better to write a separate Perl script to process the CSV output and create the Excel file. My skill level in both languages is about the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know how complex the template is, but check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/

Its a library to create excel files in python.

Comment: Also look at xlwt (and corresponding xlrd), which is forked from pyexcelerator. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Comment: pyexcelerator is not maintained anymore. Use Machin's xlwt.

Answer (score 6):

The perl libraries are [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://p3rl.org/Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX) (for .xlsx) or [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) (for .xls).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to attempt this in Perl, have a look at [Spreadsheet::Wright](http://search.cpan.org/~tobyink/Spreadsheet-Wright-0.102/lib/Spreadsheet/Wright.pm)

It has detailed examples and also allows you to highlight certain rows by making them bold, changing the colors, etc.

Specifically, this is the example that should help you:

```
my $sp=Spreadsheet::Wright->new(
    file        => 'employees.xls',
    styles      => {
        important => { font_weight => 'bold' },
    },
);
$sp->addrow(
    { content => 'First Name', font_weight => 'bold' },
    { content => 'Last Name',  font_weight => 'bold' },
    { content => 'Age',        style => 'important' },
);
$sp->addrow("John","Doe",34);
$sp->addrow("Susan","Smith",28);
```